# Angular 5 minification class.name error

Tags: angular, minify

Who faced the problem of minification class.name with Angular 5+ and who know how fix it?

I have a several classes:

```
class FirstClass {
}

class SecondClass{
}
```

And check-function like this:

```
function checkFunction() {
   const isEqual = FirstClass.name === SecondClass.name;
   console.log('isEqual -> ' + isEqual)
}
```

So, without minification I get **isEqual  -> false**, but with minification I get **isEqual  -> true**

When I investigate this deeper, I got:

without minification:

- **FirstClass.name is 'FirstClass'**
- **SecondClass.name is 'SecondClass'**

and with minification:

- **FirstClass.name is 'e'**
- **SecondClass.name is 'e'**

Does anybody have ideas???

Answer (score 0):

For javascript to get the name of the class you can use `FirstClass.constructor.name` Give it a try.

Comment: I thought about it, but than I get **FirstClass.constructor.name is 'Function'**

Comment: Could you explain more what do you want to do please.

Comment: I want to know - this is a bug of minification Angular or I need to configure the compiler.

I met with the issue, during review a task of the one of my subordinates, and I wondered why the minification violates the contract (mean **replace static constants**)

Comment: I meant, do you wanna know if both of your classes have the same name or they have name property and you want to compare the property value.

Comment: I want to know, why the minification violates the contract (mean **replace static constants**). As I know, the name of class is a static string constant...